# Split keyboard entry between two Tkinter widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, treeview

I have a window with a treeview and an entry widget. I would like to be able to write in the entry widget while still being able to use the up/down arrows to navigate the treeview. There are a few ways I've tried doing this:

1. Send all keyboard events to both widgets (I have tried using custom bind_tags, unsuccessfully)
2. Use the entry `<Up>` and `<Down>` bindings to navigate the treeview (I have not found a straightforward way to move up and down a tree with multiple parents and children, such as a file directory)
3. Use the root `<Key>` binding to selectively send raw keycodes to the entry widget so things like backspace and left/right arrow work as expected (I haven't come across a method to send keycodes/events directly to the entry widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #2 is the right approach. You will have to write methods that calculate how to move up and down the tree. You can get the currently selected item, then use the `.next()` method to get the next child of the same parent. If that returns an empty string you can get the parent (by calling `.parent()`) and call `.next()` on it. You can recursively keep doing that until you hit the end of the tree (the parent is the root node, and `.next()` returns the empty string).